# Conditional statement not working correctly in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

By clicking on save button of the form, user either updates and existing item or add a new one. For that, in `_saveForm()` method, I have implemented the following `if statement`, but it doesn't work properly. It just updates the already-existing item and when it comes to add a new one, It does not. What is the problem?

```
  Future<void> _saveForm() async {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    if (_editedItem.id != null) {
      await Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false)
          .updateItem(_editedItem.id.toString(), _editedItem);
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } else {
      try {
        await Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false).addItem(_editedItem);
      } catch (error) {
        await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('An error occurred!'),
            content: const Text('Something went wrong.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Okay'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

Followings are the methods called inside `_saveForm()` function:

```
Future<void> updateItem(String id, Item newItem) async {
    final itemIndex = _items.indexWhere((item) => item.id == id);
    if (itemIndex >= 0) {
      final url = 'https://shaparak-732ff.firebaseio.com/items/$id.json';
      await http.patch(Uri.parse(url),
          body: json.encode({
            'title': newItem.title,
            'content': newItem.content,
            'author': newItem.author,
            'category': newItem.category,
            'startColor': newItem.startColor,
            'endColor': newItem.endColor,
          }));
      _items[itemIndex] = newItem;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      
      print('...');
    }
  }
```

And the method that does not function:

```
  Future<void> addItem(Item item) {
    const url = 'https://shaparak-732ff.firebaseio.com/items.json';
    return http
        .post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      body: json.encode({
        'title': item.title,
        'content': item.content,
        'author': item.author,
        'category': item.category,
        'startColor': item.startColor,
        'endColor': item.endColor,
      }),
    )
        .then((response) {
      final newItem = Item(
        title: item.title,
        content: item.content,
        author: item.author,
        category: item.category,
        startColor: item.startColor,
        endColor: item.endColor,
        id: json.decode(response.body)['name'],
      );
      _items.add(newItem);
      // _items.insert(0, newProduct); // at the start of the list
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you try adding print statements inside the addItem function to see if it reaches there? This will help narrow where the issue is occurring.

Comment: I did it. It does not reach to the addItem()

Comment: If the `id` is not null it will never reach the `addItem` method. Did you already verified that? Use the debugger to find out what is happening, the information that you provided is not enough to help us help you. Please provide a complete working example that does not hide any relevant behavior of your application.

Comment: I second the above comment, please check if you are getting an id even for the new item.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't add your product id, you will follow this code .....

```
Future<void> addItem(Item item) {
  const url = 'https://shaparak-732ff.firebaseio.com/items.json';
  return http
    .post(
  Uri.parse(url),
  body: json.encode({
    'id': item.id,
    'title': item.title,
    'content': item.content,
    'author': item.author,
    'category': item.category,
    'startColor': item.startColor,
    'endColor': item.endColor,
  }),
)
    .then((response) {
  final newItem = Item(
    id: json.decode(response.body)['name'],
    title: item.title,
    content: item.content,
    author: item.author,
    category: item.category,
    startColor: item.startColor,
    endColor: item.endColor
  );
  _items.insert(0, newItem);
  notifyListeners();
});
}
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Hey basically your problem looks like it might be because id can never be null. So instead of

```
if (_editedItem.id != null) {
  await Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false)
      .updateItem(_editedItem.id.toString(), _editedItem);
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
```

try making it say

```
if (_editedItem.id != '') {
  await Provider.of<Items>(context, listen: false)
      .updateItem(_editedItem.id.toString(), _editedItem);
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
```